# C# OpenTelemetry against Jaeger works in Simple but not Batch

Tags: c#, jaeger, open-telemetry

Have a pretty much working environment to use for tracing, OpenTelemetry against Jaeger Tracing.
I sort of read that `Batch` for process is the preferred way then `Simple`. How ever with in .Net Framework 4.8 `Batch` dose not seem to give any results being logged.
I did a capture of packet data with Wireshark. Nothing happens when running in `Batch`.

Is there something with this configuration that is missing to have this as `ExportProcessorType.Batch` instead of `ExportProcessorType.Simple`?

```
    public TracerProvider GetTracerProvider(string host, int port)
    {           
        BackendServiceResource = ResourceBuilder.CreateDefault()
             .AddService(Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName)               
             .AddAttributes(new[]
             {
                new KeyValuePair<string, object>("MachineName", Environment.MachineName),
                new KeyValuePair<string, object>("UserName", Environment.UserName),
             });

        return Sdk.CreateTracerProviderBuilder()
        .SetResourceBuilder(BackendServiceResource)
        .SetSampler(new AlwaysOnSampler())
        .SetErrorStatusOnException(true)
        .AddSource(ActivitySource.Name)
        .AddConsoleExporter()
        .AddJaegerExporter(jeager =>
        {
            jeager.AgentHost = host;
            jeager.AgentPort = port;

            jeager.MaxPayloadSizeInBytes = 4096;

            jeager.ExportProcessorType = ExportProcessorType.Simple;
            jeager.BatchExportProcessorOptions = new BatchExportProcessorOptions<Activity>()
            {
                MaxQueueSize = 2048,
                ScheduledDelayMilliseconds = 5000,
                ExporterTimeoutMilliseconds = 30000,
                MaxExportBatchSize = 512,
            };
        })
        .Build();
    }
```

Comment: Don't forget that the AddJaegerExporter is about to be deprecated https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet/blob/main/src/OpenTelemetry.Exporter.Jaeger/README.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thought I post a solution for this sort of issue.

The reason for these problems is because in some cases as application can close down before the process is fully completed. A solution for this is `using` and making sure that all gets completed before all is valid for closure.

You can read more about it more here https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet/issues/2758